# Stop mouse pointer from sticking to the edge of display in dual monitor setup

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, display, mouse, dual-screen

I am using macOS Mojave on a MacBook Pro.

I don't know if it's just me, but I feel like the mouse pointer, from time to time, seems to stick to the edge of the monitor when I try to move it from secondary monitor to the primary monitor (the secondary monitor is to the right, primary (laptop built in monitor) to the left).

If I try to make it happen on purpose it never happens, which makes me feel like I was mistaken in the beginning, but after playing around for a while I feel like it definitely is happening, but only sometimes and I'm not sure why.

Does this annoying snap-to-monitor-edge feature have a name, and more importantly how do I disable it?

Comment: I had an issue with a 3 monitor setup. so posted the answer to it and the pictures of the fix.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There is no snap-to-monitor-edge feature or anything similar built-in into macOS Mojave (or any earlier release of macOS). You are using an external monitor with extended display mode. As described, your setup is something like this:

[image]

The display on the left is your built-in display, while the one on your right is the external, extended display.

Now, notice the horizontal alignment of the displays. When moving the mouse from external to built-in display, if you are moving the mouse along the bottom edge, the pointer will have no path to move into the built-in display shown on left, as it hits the edge of the external display.

[image]

If you move the mouse pointer vertically to appropriate height, the mouse pointer will find a way to move **into** built-in display as soon as it reaches the corner of the built-in display. You can try this by dragging the mouse pointer along the edge of external display vertically, while attempting to move the mouse pointer towards left.

If you find this behaviour interfering with your workflow, you can easily adjust the relative placement of the displays by dragging them. There are a number of variations you can try as long as the two rectangles are not totally isolated (as separate islands). Even an alignment where just the angles of the two displays is touching is possible too :)

Refer to the Apple Support document, [Use external monitors with your Mac](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT202351) for more details.

Comment: I see, this is indeed happening if I try to move the pointer through the lower part of the external (right) monitor. Thank you very much

Comment: Is there any way to make the mouse pointer come out of the corresponding location of the edge of the built-in monitor when I move it from secondary to the primary monitor? (For instance, if I move the pointer from secondary to primary at 2/3rd the height of the secondary, it should come out at 2/3rd the height of the primary). I think that's how it happens on Windows. Is there a way to do this on mac?

Comment: @user17915 Not using any built-in mechanism. I'm not aware of any 3rd party app that lets you do so.

Comment: @user17915 Your computer doesn't know anything about the physical size of the monitors—it only knows about resolution.

Comment: @user17915 It happens correctly on windows, since the default screen size of your windows laptop was the same as your external screen, but the mac book you are using has a retina screen that has a smaller total numbers of pixels than your external screen, this issue is also on Windows if you use a 4k screen in combination with an full HD external screen

Comment: @Ferrybig There is [a third-party workaround](https://superuser.com/questions/1119204/move-mouse-proportionaly-between-different-resolution-and-dpi-displays) for differing screen resolutions/scaling on Windows. Perhaps something similar exists for macOS?

Comment: This is a real issue and not dependent upon having monitors of different screen sizes. The same thing happens to me from time to time in Sierra where I have two identical monitors side-by-side.

Comment: I don't see any reason why there couldn't be an option for it to behave exactly the way as described in the second comment by @user17915, since it has nothing to do with physical size - i don't care if the mouse doesn't come out at the physically correct location - the cursor just should never stop when it is at the edge of the screen, if the other screen is aligned there.

Comment: I am having an issue where my Mac Screen and external display (where connected), is like an imaginary barrier and I have to use more mouse speed to break from 1 to the other.
My issue is not as per the answer, not sure how this answer is even warranted, surely if you are setting up external monitors you know about aligning the rectangles you had to have gone through the setup process.

Answer (score 4):

I have just accidentally also come across the problem of snap-to-monitor-edge. And the root cause was not related to any macOS feature but to the fact that when I was arranging my displays in **System Preferences** > **Displays** I have set it up with a very tiny gap between the screens.

At this time I have not even realised the slit. But the problem of the mouse pointer sticking to the edge was so annoying to me that after digging a while I realised that dropping this gap away equaled in the ability to change the display areas smoothly (without waiting at the edge).

Comment: Yes!  This was my problem.  Thank you so much.  I owe you a beer!

My issue occurred most notably when trying to move the mouse slowly from one monitor to the next.  It would get to the edge and stay there unless I slid it away again and "rammed" it through.

The problem was indeed a tiny gap between my monitors in settings.

Comment: I had the same problem and it was driving me crazy. First thought it was a new "feature" since I just updated the OS. The screens were so close in System Preferences is was not possible to see the gap and at normal mouse speed I did not noticed it. But moving the mouse slowly it would get stuck! Thanks for the help!

Comment: Amazing, on closer look I also found out that I had a 1-2px gap between my screens. :D

Answer (score 0):

This is actually the main cause of a sticking mouse at the edge with external monitors, because most people who setup external monitors know to align the edges as they see fit. however this situation (Pic) is more elusive due to the fact you can transition through the boundary above the mac but it is just sticky.

this can only really occur with 2 external monitors in the cornered configuration similar to the picture.

The answer is to move the mac position around until the grey bar or screen corner is no longer rounded.

This picture depicts a bad situation

[image]

This picture show the setup for a smooth transition between monitors:

[image]